# Подключение сторонних зависимостей в Android приложении (сейчас)

Tags: java, android, android-gradle

Решил подключить к своему проекту библиотеку vk.com.api:sdk, чтобы можно было работать с VK сервисом. Добавлял я ее следующим образом :

Сначала так implementation group: 'com.vk.api', name: 'sdk', version: '1.0.9'

А потом так implementation 'com.vk.api:sdk:1.0.9', ибо проанализировав уже подключенные автоматом зависимости, я понял, что там использовался 2 способ.

Однако после подключения проект перестал "билдиться" и выдает такую вот ошибку (не работает в обоих случаях):

[image: та самая ошибка]

До андроида я имел дело только с maven, поэтому не совсем уверен, что я правильно подключаю зависимость, но, вроде, правильно. Что делать? :)

Весь build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my_project.mini_vk_app"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.vk.api:sdk:1.0.9'


}
```

Comment: Возможно вам нужна либа именно под андроид. С ней таких проблем не будет. Если всё таки эта нужна - поищите ошибку в сети. Я на днях находил решение аналогичной проблеме, но показать смогу только во вторник

Comment: Хорошо, я подожду)

Comment: Попробуйте вот такое добавить в `android` блок в `build.gradle (module app)`: `packagingOptions {  }` А в него `exclude 'META-INF/*'` или `merge 'META-INF/*'`